# Add Info window on drawingManager 'overlaycomplete'

Tags: drawing, maps

So I am stuck on figuring out how I can add an info window to a marker during the overlaycomplete event. I have figured out how to add a title to the marker but I can't get an info window to work.... Could any help please?

Here is the code I currently have to create the title...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
  if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
     event.overlay.setTitle("Hello");
  }
});
```

Comment: I figured this one out! It was just me overlooking simple things: Below is how you do it if anyone else needs to know:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
  if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
    //event.overlay.setTitle("Hello");
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<div id="content" onmouseover="updateContent()">Hello</div>',
      maxWidth: 10
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay,'click',function(){
      infowindow.open(map,event.overlay);
    });
  }
});
```